# Change images of Gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I have a quick question.

I want to change the images of GridView if I select a RadioButton in another Activity.
In short: I want to Change the images of Gridview from Activity A from Activity B.
Sadly I get NULLPOINTER.

Here is my Code from B:

RadioButton1:

```
       SavePreferences("a0", "1");
```

RadioButton2:

```
       SavePreferences("a0", "2");
```

My SavePreferences

```
   private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences2",           MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
```

So heres Activity A

```
 public String a0 = "1";
 public Integer a1;     
 public Integer a2;
     public Integer a3;
     public Integer a4; 
     public Integer a5;
     public Integer a6;
```

In OnCreate

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String a0 = sharedPreferences.getString("a0", "1");
    Log.i("MyActivity", "3:a0= " + a0 );

   if ( a0.equals("1"))

   {         Log.i("MyActivity", "4:a0= " + a0 );

     a1=R.drawable.ic_launcher;
     a2=R.drawable.ic_launcher;
     a3=R.drawable.ic_launcher; 
     a4=R.drawable.ic_launcher; 
     a5=R.drawable.ic_launcher; 
     a6=R.drawable.ic_launcher; 

   }
   if ( a0.equals("2"))
   {                    Log.i("MyActivity", "6:a0= " + a0 );


        a1=R.drawable.test; 
    a2=R.drawable.test;
    a3=R.drawable.test; 
    a4=R.drawable.test; 
    a5=R.drawable.test; 
    a6=R.drawable.test; 

  }
```

Heres my ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

[....]


    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {


           a1 , a2,
            a3, a4,
            a5 , a6,

    };

    }
```

I set a few Logs to see where the problem is.
Log 3 says a0 = 1
but Log 4 is not reacting.

So my code doesnt enter the if loop, although a0 == 1 ??

Can anyone please explain me, where the problem is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude you have a few mistakes in the code, that are made less obvious because of the negligent coding style. Also the way you pasted your examples are unclear, because the code is out of context. You should paste every code snippet in the relevant Class.method like this:

```
class Foo {
  ...
  public bar() {
    ...
    some code;
    ...
  }
};
```

However I think I know where the problem is: you have different variables in your Adapter than in your Activity. mThumbsId is not affected by how you set up your Activity members.

You should create a constructor taking an array of ids, so that you can pass the data you want when you create the adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  Integer mThumbIds[];
  Context mContext;
  ...
  ImageAdapter(Context context, Integer thumbs[]) {
    mContext = context;
    mThumbIds = thumbs;
  }
}
```

Also please stop using such variables as Integer a1...a6 and String a0. It's easy to get them confused. Use an array instead, then you can also happily pass it to the Adapter constructor described above:

```
public Class FooActivity extends Activity {
  ...
  Integer imageSetLauncher = {
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher
  };

  Integer imageSetTest = {
    R.drawable.test,
    R.drawable.test,
    R.drawable.test,
    R.drawable.test,
    R.drawable.test,
    R.drawable.test
  };

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageAdapter adapter;
    if (a0 == "1") {
      adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imageSetLauncher);
    }
    if (a0 == "2") {
      adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imageSetTest);
    }
  }
  ...
};
```

Eventually, another question of style, please observe which variables need to be public and private. If you don't need to access a variable outside your class, but you leave it public chances are you might access it from another class which would be wrong.

The parameter mContext to the constructor in the example is not relevant for your question, just that you will of course need it when drawing your view.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I just want to know, why the if statement is wrong.
If I delete the if Statement, everything works.

could you please explain why the if statement doesnt work ?

Comment: I think your "if" statement is not wrong. The problem must be, in your Adapter who is a1..a6? Certainly Adapter.a1 is different than Activity.a1, this is why I said you should pass your IDs to the Adapter somehow. What you say about << a0 == "1">> but <<if (a0 == "1")>> not working is impossible. Try to print << Log.i("MyActivity", "3:a0= " + a0 + " if: " + (a0 == "1") ); >> - if this will print "3:a0= 1 if: true" and if really doesn't enter it's code block - then your computer is broken :-)

Comment: solved the problem: i set a0 to text instead of a number, now it works